# How to change header background image on hover menu

Tags: html, css, mousehover

I have been searching for a way to change the background image of my banner when I hover my menu bar.

here you have my html

```
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="bedrijf.html">bedrijf</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="diensten.html">diensten</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="pictures.html">foto's</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact-page.html">contacteer ons</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

So what i wanna do is when I hover over one of my buttons the background of header should change to a picture I pick for this page.

I hope this is possible it would be great.

Comment: There are no parent selectors in CSS (generally speaking). You'd need scripting. Is jQuery included in your project? It's trivial in that case.

Comment: i rather don't use jquere or javascript (it's for a school project / for my dad )

Comment: Fair enough. This isn't really possible, then. CSS selectors can go down the tree, and across in some cases, but not up.

Comment: I think you should look at some jquery/javascript solutions ([like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158171/change-background-image-of-div-on-navbar-hover)) because I don't think its possible using only css.

Comment: oke thanks for answering the i won't implement this idea

Comment: It's not possible without js. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 2):

You could do that in jQuery:

```
$("li > a").hover(function(){
 $("header").css("background-image", "img.jpg");
});
```

This code says if you hover over an element with a-Tag which is in a li-Tag then it changes the background-image of the header to img.jpg.

Now if you want that the background-image changes back if you don't hover then add this code too:

```
$("li > a").mouseleave(function(){
 $("header").css("background-image", "none");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use pseudo elements (`:before`) on the LI's when you hover over them.
It's a bit hacky, but does work and without javascript too.

working demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ezjjyptk/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I've come up with. Basically, add an empty, absolutely positioned div inside each `<li>` element, and move it up from behind the header on hover.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkwx6s9n/)

```
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">home</a>
          <div style="background:green">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="bedrijf.html">bedrijf</a>
          <div style="background:yellow">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="diensten.html">diensten</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="pictures.html">foto's</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact-page.html">contacteer ons</a></li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
ul li a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
ul li:hover div {
  z-index: 1;
}
ul li div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's impossible without javascript, but I certainly wouldn't call this code pretty

```css
.fixed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.show1:hover + #header1 {
  opacity: 1;
}
.show2:hover + #header2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
.show3:hover + #header3 {
  opacity: 1;
}
.show4:hover + #header4 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a class="show1" href="index.html">Show 1</a>
  <img class="fixed" id="header1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6f/Color_blocks.svg/800px-Color_blocks.svg.png" />
</li>
<li>
  <a class="show2" href="bedrijf.html">Show 2</a>
  <img class="fixed" id="header2" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/534d1b21e4b077040469bae0/t/5362730de4b04c365eb65a37/1398960956409/The+two+colour+shirt" />
</li>
<li>
  <a class="show3" href="diensten.html">Show 3</a>
  <img class="fixed" id="header3" src="http://i1.wp.com/makeapowerfulpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Drunk-Tank-Pink.png" />
</li>
<li>
  <a class="show4" href="pictures.html">Show 4</a>
  <img class="fixed" id="header4" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-YFX5nFtmjiA/T7co_rB3keI/AAAAAAAAI0c/EkNV9tX3xt8/s920/color%2Bwheel%2Bstar%2Bblock%2Blogo%2Bv1.jpg" />
</li>
```